# rabbitmq queue clear after restart

Tags: vb.net, rabbitmq, queue, restart

I have installed **RabbitMQ** on windows server 2012 64 Bit.

I Tested Publishing And Consuming Parts with Huge Data Everything is fine, the only problem i am facing is the messages in a queue are getting lost after RabbitMQServer restart.

I am using VB.Net SDK of RabbitMQ.

I am setting `"Durable"` property of Queue Declare to true, and `DeliveryMode BasicQueueProperties to "2"` to make the Messages persistent. But still the messages are getting lost after my server restart.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you declaring your queue  `channel.QueueDeclare("queue", true, false, false, null);` ie. with exclusive and auto delete set to false?

If yes, try to check your queue property using the web console or the [rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)

Answer (score 12):

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

In this page **Message durability** on RabbitMQ, it's explained good:

> At this point we're sure that the task_queue queue won't be lost even if RabbitMQ restarts. Now we need to mark our messages as persistent - by setting IBasicProperties.Persistent to true.
>
> ```
> var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
> properties.Persistent = true;
> ```
>
> ###### Note on message persistence
>
> Marking messages as persistent doesn't fully guarantee that a message
> won't be lost. Although it tells RabbitMQ to save the message to disk,
> there is still a short time window when RabbitMQ has accepted a
> message and hasn't saved it yet. Also, RabbitMQ doesn't do fsync(2)
> for every message -- it may be just saved to cache and not really
> written to the disk. The persistence guarantees aren't strong, but
> it's more than enough for our simple task queue. If you need a
> stronger guarantee then you can use publisher confirms.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us. +1